# How to retrieve the string id you defined (not integer id) in AndroidStudio, and Object Tags

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to make a calculator app in AndroidStudio. Originally, I used Buttons, and to retrieve the number of a button pressed, the function btn.getText() worked perfectly. I've since replaced the Buttons with ImageButtons, with the number now represented in the image.

My plan was to give all ImageButtons ids in the vein of 'btn0', 'btn1', and so on, then do something like
`Character number = imgbtn.getId().charAt(imgbtn.length()-1);`. This, however, fails miserably, as the `id` is apparently an automatically assigned int, and not the id I set.

Is there a way to access the string id property that I defined?

Alternatively, I saw mention of a `getTag()` function in my prior googling for solutions that looks like it might be useful in this situation, but I can't find an ImageButton tag property where I can set it.

---

**Solved my specific issue:** I just discovered that I can set the tag in the Text view, by adding `android:tag="x"` to the relevant ImageButtons (or that I could call `imgbtn.setTag()` to the same effect). I'm going to submit this anyway, in case someone has a similar issue in the future.

---

### Lingering Questions

My question about accessing one's defined string id still stands. Is there a way to do that, in case I'd ever like to?

Also, what's an Object Tag, such as it would be used in `imgbtn.setTag(<Object tag>)`? I can't find any documentation.

Comment: I am not really sure about your first question, but, the setTag accepts an object, only in order to give you the option to set there any type of object. Just remember to cast it back when using the getTag method. For example, if you add an String using setTag("Sample String"); then to get it back needs to be done like this String tag = (String)imgbtn.getTag();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At compile time, all resources are compiled in to a class called R.Java. When you say findViewById(R.id.xxx) what you are actually doing is pointing to a static reference of a final integer called "xxx" that has been hardcoded into this Java file. If you'd like to view this, navigate to the build directory after you've built your project and go to generated, source, debug (or release) then through your project until you see R.java

In other words, the String of the id is not present at runtime.

Comment: "...the String of the id is not present at runtime." - That's not quite accurate, though reflection would be required to retrieve a field name from the `R` class.

Comment: I'll add the reflection code to the answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Oh, no worries! I was just nitpicking, for completeness' sake. There's really no need to use reflection in this case; there are simpler, better alternatives. Cheers!